# Concatenating two arrays with alternating values

Tags: java, arrays, concatenation

What is the best way to concatenate two arrays with alternating values?

Let's say `array1` is:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

`array2` is:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

I want to combine these two arrays, so that the result is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

In Java:

```
int[] a1 = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
int[] a2 = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };
int[] concat = new int[a1.length * 2];
for (int i = 0; i < concat.length; i++) {
    // concatenation
}
System.out.println(concat.toString());
// should be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

**Update:** No sorting is required, as the arrays are already sorted, using `Arrays.sort(array)`

Comment: Do you want to sort the result or do you want to pick elements alternatively from the two arrays?

Comment: depends what the meaning of best is for you. Can you use external libaries or do you have to do it by yourself?

Comment: Assuming equals lengths and java 8, you could do `int[] concat = IntStream.range(0, a1.length).flatMap(i -> IntStream.of(a1[i], a2[i])).toArray();`

Comment: you want the result to be sorted?

Comment: It seems arraycopy method in java.lang.System is perfect for you. Its also native one so you can't be faster than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic way

```
int[] concat = new int[a1.length * 2];
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
    concat[index++] = a1[i];
    concat[index++] = a2[i];
}
```

assuming that both array will be of same size.

Comment: thanks for the correction .. increement should be done in both statement.

Comment: But this assumes both arrays `a1` and `a2` of are equal length and will fail if they are not :)

Comment: @Mustafasabit In my case they are equal length. Otherwise it would fail, right. Good point. If someone faces the same problem, it should be considered.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
int[] concat = new int[a1.length + a2.length];

int k = 0, m = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < concat.length; i++) {
    if( k < al.length && a1[k] <= a2[m])
        concat[i] = a1[k++];
    else
        concat[i] = a2[m++];
}
```

---

**NB**: The result will be sorted as in your desired output.

Comment: it is not guaranteed that a1 is longer than a2.

Answer (score 2):

Put the elements of both array in a list and then sort it.You can use lambdas also

```
Integer[] a1 = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
Integer[] a2 = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(a1));
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(a2));
System.out.println("Before Sorting "+list);
Collections.sort(list,(a, b) -> Integer.compare(a,b));
System.out.println("After Sorting "+list);
```

Output

```
Before Sorting [1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8]
After Sorting [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to zip together any length arrays (where then lengths differ, the remaining is appended to the result):

```
public static int[] zip(int[] a, int[] b){
    int[] result = new int[a.length + b.length];
    int index = 0;
    final int minLen = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < minLen; i++) {
        result[index++] = a[i];
        result[index++] = b[i];
    }
    if(a.length > minLen)
      System.arraycopy(a, minLen, result, index, a.length - minLen);
    else if(b.length > minLen)
      System.arraycopy(b, minLen, result, index, b.length - minLen);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use two variables in your loop like this

```
int[] a1 = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
int[] a2 = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };
int[] concat = new int[a1.length + a2.length];
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i+j < concat.length;) {
    if(i<a1.length) {
        concat[i+j] = a1[i++];
    }
    if(j<a2.length) {
        concat[i+j] = a2[j++];
    }

}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(concat));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This if it solves ur problem

```
int[] a1 = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
int[] a2 = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };
int[] concat = new int[a1.length + a2.length];
System.arraycopy(a1, 0, concat, 0, a1.length);
System.arraycopy(a2, 0, concat, a1.length, a2.length);
Arrays.sort(concat);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(concat));
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are utility methods for example `addALL()` method from [ArrayUtil](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29) class. But what they do is simple concatenate. For your problem you need to write your own logic. For example the following code ensures correct alternate concatenation even if arrays are of unequal length.

```
    int[] a1 = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
    int[] a2 = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 122 };
    int totalLen = a1.length + a2.length;
    int[] concat = new int[totalLen];// I made a change here incase the
                                        // arrays are not of equal length
    int i = 0; // this will be the concat array index counter
    int j1 = 0; // this will be the a1 array index counter
    int j2 = 0; // this will be the a2 array index counter
    while (i < totalLen) {

        if ((j1 < a1.length)) {
            concat[i] = a1[j1];
            i++;
            j1++;
        }

        if ((j2 < a2.length)) {
            concat[i] = a2[j2];
            i++;
            j2++;
        }
    }
```