# C# Merging two arrays alternatively

Tags: c#, arrays

If I have two arrays of different lengths, how can I merge them so that the elements from each array will alternate one after the other, starting with the first element of the first array?

For example, these two arrays:

```
string[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string[] operations = { +, +, + };
```

With an output of:

```
string[] output = { 1, +, 2, +, 3, +, 4 };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating two arrays with alternating values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33144667/concatenating-two-arrays-with-alternating-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming length of `numbers` is 1 or longer and always 1 element longer than the length of `operations`:

```
string[] numbers = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
string[] operations = { "+", "+", "+" };

string[] merged = new string[numbers.Length + operations.Length];
merged[0] = numbers[0];

for (int i = 1, j = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    merged[j++] = operations[i - 1];
    merged[j++] = numbers[i];
}
```